# Load image to imageview directly using aws s3 without downloading to local storage in android from digital ocean

Tags: android, amazon-s3, cloud, digital-ocean, android-glide

So, iam trying to get image from digital cloud spaces with s3 credential and presaged url, so that I can use that Url in glide to download

AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
.withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com", "sgp1"))
.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret))).build();

```
    java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
    long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
    expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * 30;
    expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest("\n" +
            "sample",
            "my.png").withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .withExpiration(expiration);
    URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

with  implementation platform('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.825')
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
these dependency

it gives, below error
Process: com.sunny.flat_belly_12days, PID: 15403
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/management/MBeanServerFactory;
at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.getMBeanServer(MBeans.java:111)

and if I use -
AmazonS3Client s3;
BasicAWSCredentials credentials;

```
String key = "xxxxx"; //SpacesKey
String secret = "yyyyyyyyy"; //Spaces Secret key

credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret);
s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

s3.setEndpoint("https://RegionName.digitaloceanspaces.com"); //endpoint

Date expires = new Date (new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60); // 1 minute to expire
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey);  //generating the signatured url

generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expires);
URL url = s3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

with java-sdk-core' and java-sdk-s3' dependency then

it shows 'AmazonS3Client' deprecated and returns not accessible means access denied

Comment: If you have a solution you can post your own answer. This site does not limit who can answer because a future visitor could have a better solution or a different approach. Question and answers are meant to benefit everyone, not just you.

Comment: That I posted was right, may be iam using wrong keys that is why access denied after creating new keys it is working, it still shows AmazonS3Client(credentials) deprecated, dont know what to do